# How do you use the setState() function as part of a Flutter widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

Here's a Dart Stack that I'd like to be able to reuse:

```dart
Stack(children: [
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: IconButton(
        splashRadius: 20,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded),
        tooltip: 'decrease bonus by 1',
        onPressed: () => setState(() => value -= 1)),
  ),
  Container(
      width: 90,
      child: Center(child: Text(value.toString()))),
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: IconButton(
        splashRadius: 20,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up_rounded),
        tooltip: 'increase bonus by 1',
        onPressed: () => setState(() => value += 1)),
  ),
])
```

Ideally, I'd like to turn this stack into a widget or function that I could call with a Widget like `ArrowIncrement(value: value)` or a function like `ArrowIncrement(value)`, but I can't get it to work due to the error `the function 'setState' isn't defined`.

Is there a solution or workaround for this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by turning the `Stack` into a function? You can create a function that returns a `Widget` or refactor your `onPressed` method to be a separate function. Something like `_increaseValue(value) => setState(() => value += 1);`

Comment: Yeah, ideally I'd like to create a function that returns the entire block of code above as a widget; unfortunately it didn't work due to the setState() function.

Comment: Make a another "stateful" widget which returns this stack widget from it's build method! I guess you are using stateless widget, in stateless widget you cannot use setState method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap it into your own widget:

```
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final ValueChanged<int> onValueChanged;
  final int value;
  
  MyWidget({required this.value, required this.onValueChanged});
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: IconButton(
        splashRadius: 20,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded),
        tooltip: 'decrease bonus by 1',
        onPressed: () => onValueChanged(value-1)),
  ),
  Container(
      width: 90,
      child: Center(child: Text(value.toString()))),
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: IconButton(
        splashRadius: 20,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up_rounded),
        tooltip: 'increase bonus by 1',
        onPressed: () => onValueChanged(value+1)),
  ),
]);
  }
}
```

... and then use it like this in your build method (assuming you have a variable called currentBonusValue in your state):

```
MyWidget(
    value: currentBonusValue, 
    onValueChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => currentBonusValue = newValue),
)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use a change notifier provider like this :

step one make change notifier class

```
class Change with Changenotifier{
int value = 0;

void inc(){
 value += 1;
 notifierliseners()
}
}
void dec(){
 value -= 1;
 notifierliseners()
}
}
```

then call the provider in your widget
but before this, you must wrap your widget with changenotifierprovider widget
I think you know how to do that

```
class Thewidget extend Statelesswidget{
 Widget build(buildcontext context){
 var provider = provider.of<change>(context);
return Stack(children: [
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
    child: IconButton(
        splashRadius: 20,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down_rounded),
        tooltip: 'decrease bonus by 1',
        onPressed: () => provider.dec())),
  ),
  Container(
      width: 90,
      child: Center(child: Text(provider.value.toString()))),
  Align(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    child: IconButton(
        splashRadius: 20,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_up_rounded),
        tooltip: 'increase bonus by 1',
        onPressed: () => provider.inc())),
  ),
])
}
}
```

when you call dec or inc methods the widget will be reloaded due to notifierlisners in the two methods

Answer (score -3):

Try replacing => with  {} :

```
OnPressed : () {
 Setstate(() {
value +=1
};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the response! Unfortunately this still doesn't work; I believe it's due to the setState function being designed to only work in the context of a stateful widget.